# How to find a class but the class starts with css-

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

Console prints: `[]` but the div isn't empty:

```
<div data-cy="ws-run-btn" class="css-1ksc682">
```

Code:

```
requester = requests.get("https://...").text
hsource = BeautifulSoup(requester, 'lxml')

nono = hsource.find_all("div", {"class": 'css-1ksc682'})
print(nono)
```

I tried to use the `data-cy` also.

Comment: *Always and first of all, take a look at your soup to see if all the expected ingredients are in place.* possibly the content of the page is rendered dynamically and is therefore not available. without further information on the page, however, we can only speculate. feel free to add relevant details to the question. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS selectors to find elements on a page doesn't work so well with wildcard values. If you find a `class` or `id` on one of the parent elements that is consistent, then you can select and drill down.

For example, if you know that `data-cy` is an attribute present on every `div` that you are attempting to select, you could use:

```py
requester = requests.get("https://...").text
hsource = BeautifulSoup(requester, 'lxml')

nono = hsource.select("[data-cy]")
print(nono)
```

This uses the attribute as a selector. You can learn more about CSS selectors in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

Alternatively, if you can find some parent element you can select it and the `div` elements inside:

```html
<div id="some-parent">
  <div data-cy="ws-run-btn" class="css-1ksc682">
  <div data-cy="ws-run-btn" class="css-1ksc683">
  <div data-cy="ws-run-btn" class="css-1ksc684">
</div>
```

Here you could select them via:

```py
requester = requests.get("https://...").text
hsource = BeautifulSoup(requester, 'lxml')

nono = hsource.select("#some-parent>*")
print(nono)
```

The `#` character is used to denote an `id`. The `.` is used to denote a class being selected (e.g. `.some-class`). An attribute is selected with the `[]` syntax.

An easy way for you to test out your CSS selectors is to open the website you are scraping and open the dev tools. From there you can locate the console and enter:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('your selectors here')
```

This should highlight the elements on the page being selected and show you what is being selected. There are many alternatives to this and many browsers support the shorthand: `$$('your selector')` or to select the first instance: `$('your selector')`.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code in this sandbox: https://codehs.com/sandbox/id/python-3-8NYWnJ and it works as expected when the element is in the html parsed by BeautifulSoup. To be sure of that, I have hard-coded the html content. If you run the code in the sandbox, you will see that it gets printed in the console.

To see if the element exists in the html you fetched, print it before parsing and manually look for it. It might be that the element you are trying to find is added dynamically to the page, after an event or user interaction, and it will not be in the page when you first fetch its content.

Comment: (It is a very good comment, but not a good answer) Everyone knows that this should work under normal conditions. But without further information, how can you expect that page to be the same as what you have **hard-coded**? I believe this shouldn't be an answer.